# How to enable user fill in of Acro Form PDFs in HTML5 without Adobe Acrobat plugin

Tags: html, pdf, svg

I would like to know, in general broad-brush terms, how it is possible to interact with  AcroForm PDFs in HTML5 in the web browser without using Adobe Acrobat plug-in or any embedded java applet or ActiveX.

Would the PDF be rendered as SVG with some sort of overlay whereby the interactive fields get presented as absolutely positioned HTML INPUTs?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not something you want to do unless you are in complete control of the forms you plan on presenting in this way... and if that's the case, your better off collecting the data in HTML 5 forms and then populating the PDF using a library on your server.

AcroForm PDF files often contain calculations, validation, and formatting JavaScripts that have their own model and would be difficult to project into browser-based JavaScript. Even simple field validations and formatting that can be selected through the authoring UI rely on built-in JavaScript to function so it's hard to avoid these.

If you are the author of the form or are in complete control of the authoring process but you don't want to rely on a browser plugin, why bother with the PDF for the data entry? Collect the input for the fields and then programmatically add those values to the PDF, flatten the form, and then present that result via one of the various PDF to HTML5 rendering tools.